# Kubuntu MyLiveCD?

Tags: kubuntu

In PCLinuxOS I use their MyLiveCD (command line) to make a system backup iso which I can put on a usb stick with their LiveUSBCreator and essentially remaster my installation on another computer, and it works very well.

Does Kubuntu have something like MyLiveCD?  I see where Kubuntu has LiveUSBCreator, but I don't see any MyLiveCD to make the system iso file.

1 yr PCLinuxOS user trying Kubuntu on 2nd laptop, very impressed with it, may move to Kubuntu entirely.

Answer (score 1):

As a [system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc), I use [CloneZilla](http://CloneZilla.ORG) *which I use* to back up everything except `/home/` and [BackInTime](http://backintime.le-web.org/) for data back-up (my `/home/`).  I've tested system restores already a few times after I've messed up my system and data restores after I've deleted a file I didn't want to delete...  **;-)**

You, on the other hand, might want to use CloneZilla to back up everything, depending on your needs!

An alternative for you might be [TimeShift](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html) which allows you to back up entire systems with differential back-ups keeping each differential back-up completely restoreable... (I've read all documentation of all back-up programs around and this one will be next on my list to to test whether it's good enough to replace my CloneZilla/BackInTime combo)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: You're digging in old dirt. That guy was not seen since Feb 5th that year, so I doubt he will ever come back. Besides, I don't really see where your backup-only answer fits the question...? :-/

Comment: @ByteCommander: :D  I didn't notice I was digging in old dirt... It's just that TimeShift looks promising even to me!  ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Of course it has a live CD. How did you install it? The normal way is to download an iso image and burn a CD/DVD of it or take it onto an USB stick. But to access your data, you can use any other Linux-based live system, too.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  Of course Kubuntu comes as live iso.  I'm talking about making another live iso of my installation that preserves user settings and everything else.  Kubuntu doesn't seem to to have that.

Comment: You mean you want to have a persistent live installation on a USB stick?

Comment: MyLiveCD has three purposes on my PCLinuxOS machine, system backup, run from usb stick to fix disk errors, and "clone" the installation on another computer.  I have successfully done all 3 with it.  Just wish Kubuntu had MyLiveCD or something like it.  It's the only thing preventing me from abandoning PCLinuxOS and going full Kubuntu.

Comment: And you can do those things as well with any Ubuntu live disk / stick. Just for cloning, you would probably either chose another bootable program (e.g. clonezilla) or add a suitable app to your live Ubuntu system which is possible (but I can't tell you how as I never needed to do that yet).

Comment: @ByteCommander: See other answer...  >:)